# cin and char array pointer in struct

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct, cin

As a c++ beginner I've written the following code:

```
int main(void){
struct car{
    char * make[200];
    int manfYear;
};

int num=0;

cout << "How many cars do you wish to catalogue? ";
cin >> num;
car * Cars = new car [num]; 

for (int i=1;i<=num;i++){
    cout << "Car #" << i << ":" << endl << "Please enter the make: ";
    cin.getline(*Cars->make,200);
    cout << "Please enter the year made: ";
    cin >> Cars->manfYear;
}
```

My problem is that I can't get my head round a problem where I get a segfault when running the program at the point I need to enter the model of the car. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

As far as I understand it I'm passing a pointer to the array "make" which should make it work. Is my understanding way off?

Thanks in advance
Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Four issues I see right away:

**Issue 1**

In your `struct`, you have:

`char * make[200];`

In English, this is saying, "create an array of 200 pointers to character", when I think you want to say, "create an array of 200 characters."  So you should have instead:

`char make[200]`.

**Issue 2**

You are looping by starting at `1`.  This will skip the first car in the array - remember arrays are zero-indexed.  So you should have instead:

`for (int i = 0 ; i < num ; i++)`

and for display purposes, you could say:

`cout << "Car #" << (i+1) << ":" << endl << "Please enter the make: ";`

**Issue 3**

Where you say:

`cin.getline(*Cars->make,200);`

and

`cin >> Cars->manfYear;`

Where in these lines are you specifying which car the user is populating?  Nowhere.  If you are looping with `i`, then you need to actually mention `i`.  These should work:

`cin.getline(Cars[i].make,200);`

and

`cin >> Cars[i].manfYear;`

Notice that we are using `.`, not `->`.  This is because the items in the `Cars` array are actual instances, not pointers.  The `Cars` array is itself a pointer, but not its contents.

**Issue 4**

All credit to [@Ben C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1301901/ben-c) who pointed this out first:  mixing the `>>` operator with `getline()` function on `cin` can lead to strange behavior, with leftover `CR`'s from `>>` going into the `getline()` call.  You could use either all `>>` (disadvantage: you don't have the `200` limit enforced when reading the make) or all `cin.getline()` (disadvantage: you will have to use string buffers and then convert them for number of cars and year), or put `cin.ignore()` after each invocation of `>>`, like so:

```
cin >> num;
cin.ignore();
```

and

```
cin >> Cars[i].manfYear;
cin.ignore();
```

Again, all credit to [@Ben C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1301901/ben-c) for noticing this first.

**Last But Not Least**

By convention, classes/structs have capital names, and variables have lowercase / camelcase names.  Consider renaming the `struct` from `car` to `Car`, and the array from `Cars` to `cars`.  In other words, the reverse of the capitalization you have right now.

Finally, I concur with all the other posters here:  you should consider using `string` instead of `char` arrays.

Answer (score 2):

First, use `string` instead of poor old C `char[]`.

Next: you don't want `char * make[200];`. You want `char make[200];`. `char * make[200]` is an array of 200 pointers to `char`s, which can be used as 200 null-terminated strings - but then, you would have to `new[]` each of them. Just use `char make[200];` and `cin.getline(Cars->make, 200);`.

Comment: Brilliant. All makes sense now. Much appreciated.

Comment: Now I'm confused with what's happening, I've now got the following code:
    int main(void){
 struct car{
  char make[200];
  int manfYear;
 };

 int num=0;

 cout << "How many cars do you wish to catalogue? ";
 cin >> num;
 car * Cars = new car [num]; 
 
 for (int i=0;i<num;i++){
  cout << "Car #" << i+1 << ":" << endl << "Please enter the make: ";
  cin.getline(Cars[i].make,200);
  cin.get();
  cout << "Please enter the year made: ";
  cin >> Cars[i].manfYear;
  //Cars++;
 }

Now I'm not even being given the chance to enter the manfyear, the program just runs to but prints random data.

Answer (score 2):

`char * make[200]` declares an array of 200 pointers;  I'm guessing this isn't what you're after.

If you're simply looking to store a string, I'd recommend taking a look at the C++ `string` type instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    struct car
    {
        string make;
        int manfYear;
    };

    int num=0;

    cout << "How many cars do you wish to catalogue? ";
    cin >> num;
    car * Cars = new car [num]; 

    for (int i=1;i<=num;i++)
    {
        cout << "Car #" << i << ":" << endl << "Please enter the make: ";
        std::cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, Cars[i-1].make);
        cout << "Please enter the year made: ";
        cin >> Cars[i-1].manfYear;
    }
}
```

There were also a couple of other minor niggles with your code.

1) You had been using `Cars->manfYear` - this will only ever point you to the first element of your array.   I'm assuming you don't want that;  using the subscripting syntax as per `Cars[i-1].manfYear` will access an individual car object in your array.  (Remember that array indexes start from zero! - it would actually make more idiomatic sense for your **for** loop variable to start at zero as well really)

2) Be wary of the way `std::getline` and the `>>` symbol work together.    the `>>` (stream extraction operator) often leaves any newline characters, which means you might see "odd" behaviour with your calls to getline.   If you're mixing the two together, then using something like `std::cin.ignore()` will help you discard the newline character.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `char *make[200]` is not a string of max 200 characters but 200 pointers to `char`.

Second thing: you are dereferencing the pointer in `cin.getline` with `*`: what happens is that you obtain the value contained in first cell of the 200 `char*` pointers. But you didn't initialize the single pointers, just the higher level one, so you get a segfault.

Just change `char* make[200]` to `char make[200]` and `*Cars->make` to `Cars[i].make`.

Comment: s/`->`/`.`/. `Cars` is a `car*`, not a `car**`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, arrays in C++ are indexed from 0..n-1, so your loop needs to run from

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) { ... }
```

Secondly, you've declared `make` as a 200-element array of *pointer* to `char`; this is most likely *not* what you want.  If `make` is supposed to store a character string, declare it as a plain array of `char`:

```
struct car{
      char make[200];
      int manfYear;      
};
```

Finally, rewrite your `getline` call as

```
cin.getline(Cars[i].make, sizeof Cars[i].make); // fixed per comment below
```

Even though `Cars` is declared as a pointer, you can use the subscript operator on it *as though* it were an array; by doing so, you implicitly dereference `Cars`, since `a[i]` is interpreted as `*(a + i)`.  This also means that you will use the `.` component selection operator as opposed to the `->` operator, since the type of `Cars[i]` is `car`, not `car *`.